# How to get correct responses/error logs from Sendgrid.php file? even if it fails, "fetch" is always a 200 response currently

Tags: php, fetch, fetch-api, sendgrid

Endgoal: To get correct logs back from the fetch request. Currently, even if SendGrid fails and gives a `5XX` error, the front-end still logs a `200` error

---

I am currently using JavaScript front-end to submit a form to a sendgrid.php file to handle mail. However, I am currently using the fetch API for this.

When submitting a request, even if Sendgrid fails, I still get a `200` response. Below is an example of the response I get everytime:

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: "https://website.local/sendgrid.php"
```

Here is my code for sending the email.

single.php

```
<script>

const remindMeForm = document.getElementById('remindMe');

remindMeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const jobTitle = document.querySelector('#jobTitle').innerText;
    const jobReminder__message = document.querySelector('#jobReminder__message');
    const currentUrl = window.location.href;
    const form = document.querySelector('#remindMe');
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    formData.append('jobTitle', jobTitle);
    formData.append('currentUrl', currentUrl);
    fetch('/sendgrid.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData        
    }).then(function(res) {
        // this is where the response should appear, but I keep getting a 200 response
        console.log('res: ', res);
        jobReminder__message.innerHTML = 'Thank you for your interest in ' + jobTitle + '. A reminder has been scheduled 24 hours from now.';
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // this is where the error should appear
        console.log('err: ', err);
    })
} );

    </script>
```

sendgrid.php

```
<?php
require_once('./config.php');
require("./sendgrid/sendgrid-php.php");

$emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
$jobTitle = $_POST['jobTitle'];
$currentUrl = $_POST['currentUrl'];


use SendGrid\Mail\To;
use SendGrid\Mail\Cc;
use SendGrid\Mail\Bcc;
use SendGrid\Mail\From;
use SendGrid\Mail\Content;
use SendGrid\Mail\Mail;
use SendGrid\Mail\Personalization;
use SendGrid\Mail\Subject;
use SendGrid\Mail\Header;
use SendGrid\Mail\CustomArg;
use SendGrid\Mail\SendAt;
use SendGrid\Mail\Attachment;
use SendGrid\Mail\Asm;
use SendGrid\Mail\MailSettings;
use SendGrid\Mail\BccSettings;
use SendGrid\Mail\SandBoxMode;
use SendGrid\Mail\BypassListManagement;
use SendGrid\Mail\Footer;
use SendGrid\Mail\SpamCheck;
use SendGrid\Mail\TrackingSettings;
use SendGrid\Mail\ClickTracking;
use SendGrid\Mail\OpenTracking;
use SendGrid\Mail\SubscriptionTracking;
use SendGrid\Mail\Ganalytics;
use SendGrid\Mail\ReplyTo;


$mail = new Mail();

$apiKey = constant('SENDGRID_API_KEY');

$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$personalization0 = new Personalization();
$personalization0->addTo(new To($emailAddress, $emailAddress));

$sendAt = time() + (24 * 60 * 60);


// $personalization0->setSendAt(new SendAt($sendAt));

// $personalization0->addTo(new To("enquiries@hiddenpartners.com", "Julia Doe"));
// $personalization0->addCc(new Cc("enquiries@hiddenpartners.com", "Jane Doe"));
// $personalization0->addBcc(new Bcc("enquiries@hiddenpartners.com", "Jim Doe"));
$mail->addPersonalization($personalization0);


$mail->setFrom(new From("enquiries@hiddenpartners.com", "Job Reminder - " . $jobTitle));

$mail->setReplyTo(new ReplyTo("enquiries@hiddenpartners.com", "HiddenName"));

$mail->setSubject(new Subject("Job Reminder - " . $jobTitle));

$mail->addContent(new Content("text/html", "<p style='font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;'>Thank you for expressing an interest in the <strong><a href=". $currentUrl . ">" . $jobTitle . "</strong> role.<br/><br/>This is your requested reminder so if you’re interested in this fantastic opportunity and you would like to discuss this role with one of our team, please send us your CV to <strong>enquiries@hiddenpartners.com</strong> quoting the TP reference number or call us on <strong>01223623510</strong> for a confidential discussion.</p>"));


$request_body = $mail;

try {
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {

// should the error not send here back to single.php?
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the response code in your `catch` block.

```php
try {
  ...
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  http_response_code(500);
  echo 'Caught exception: '.  $ex->getMessage();
}
```

If the exception contains the response code from SendGrid then you can probably use that.

`http_response_code($ex->statusCode());`